# Отправить письмо с несуществующего адреса на gmail посредством telnet mail

Tags: smtp, gmail, telnet

Стоит задача отправить письмо с анонимного адреса вида:

`<что-то>@spam.ru`

на адрес вида:

`<что-то>@gmail.com`

Сделать это необходимо посредством SMTP. Проблема в следующем: в универе есть по крайне мере 2 известных мне SMTP сервера. Пробовал отправлять с обоих, получается, но только на mail, yandex и прочие подобные, но никак не на gmail, туда просто не доходит, хотя пишет, что письмо отправлено. Как быть? Преподаватель говорит, что это вполне реально, но нужно подумать. Думал много и долго, никак не получается.